# HTML or hyperlink in EKEvent notes

Tags: ios, objective-c, ekevent

I am on iOS7/8 trying to place a hyperlink in the "notes" property of an EKEvent for the calendar. Is it possible somehow (display HTML in the notes or any other way)?

Alternatively can I somehow set a clickable placeholder to the URL in the "URL" property of an EKEvent like it´s done in an HTML anchor tag?